# Control not reaching my side menu(master view of splitviewcontroller in ipad) ios xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a sign in button in  my side menu.if the user is signed in then it should show sign out.i am setting a

```
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setbool:YES ForKey:IS_USER_SIGNIN]
```

and i am checking it in the side menu for deciding what label to display.It sometime not trigger in iphone and ipad.I am using

```
swrevealViewController
```

in iphone. The control will not reach the side menu.It happens only sometimes.What are the possible reasons?Any idea?any suggestion is accepted.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using setbool in your if-clause, but it should be boolForKey:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  boolForKey:IS_USER_SIGNIN])
```

Use the setbool-method, when an user has logged in and out successfully.

Comment: sorry.That was a mistake in the question.The actual problem is that the control is not reaching the side panel Viewcontroller.Thank you for your time.